# Very Small Data But Huge Database File Size On MongoDB

Tags: linux, mongodb, server-monitoring

I have very small database:

```
> db.stats();
{
    "db" : "oyun",
    "collections" : 29,
    "objects" : 2557,
    "avgObjSize" : 355.83418068048496,
    "dataSize" : 909868,
    "storageSize" : 2410483712,
    "numExtents" : 64,
    "indexes" : 44,
    "indexSize" : 605024,
    "fileSize" : 4226809856,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

My total database size is bytes but my system.indexes kb ! And total file space consumption is huge ! This database holds holds only near 1 MB data.

```
> db.system.indexes.stats();
{
    "ns" : "oyun.system.indexes",
    "count" : 44,
    "size" : 3924,
    "avgObjSize" : 89.18181818181819,
    "storageSize" : 2408275968,
    "numExtents" : 20,
    "nindexes" : 0,
    "lastExtentSize" : 630562816,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 0,
    "indexSizes" : {

    },
    "ok" : 1
}

[root@guybrush /]#  find . -type f -size +200000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
./data/journal/prealloc.2: 1.0G
./data/journal/j._13: 1.0G
./data/journal/j._12: 1.0G
./data/mongodb/main/oyun.3: 512M
./data/mongodb/main/oyun.2: 256M
./data/mongodb/main/oyun.5: 2.0G
./data/mongodb/main/oyun.4: 1.0G
```

How can i shrink my database ? i tried repairDatabase command.

Comment: is it a ReplicaSet? I've found the entire space for the RS gets reserved right off the bat.

Comment: MongoDB preallocates the next file to be filled, for each database. Check your 'dataSize' is very low but 'storageSize' is high. I hope this will give you an idea : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database